# Setting up apache for development enviroment

Tags: apache

I'm working on the development of an webapp, I'm using Apache, by default I have the app's stored on `/var/www/`. My problem is the following:

Inside `/var/www` I have done a `git clone xxx` so I have my proyect in `/var/www/xxx`. Now, to be able to let apache run those files I have to change the ownership of those files to www-data (ubuntu). If I want to work there I should use `sudo {editor} file`, and if I chnage the file permissions I will change the files permissions on the repository.

What would be a correct way to make all of this work without screwing everything?

Answer (score 0):

The avoid this without using `sudo chmod -R 777 *` you must add your user to the apache group. In ubuntu, the apache group is: `www-data` in other distros it could be `apache2` or `httpd`.

To add the user to the group use: `useradd -G {group-name} username` in Ubuntu this would be `useradd -G www-data username`

usually `/var/www` have 664 permissions, so any user inside the owner group can write and read the files, so, if you add yourself to the group, you will be able to edit the files without problem.